# Installing Japanese language as system language make me unable to access Keyboard Setting

Tags: settings, keyboard, language

After installing Japanese as my system language, I can not access the Keyboard Setting in System Setting anymore. Clicking the icon brings me to a crash report window.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, installed fcitx.